# Commands in CloudEvents specification

Tags: microservices, cloudevents

We are adopting [CloudEvents](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec) specification in my organization. I really like the idea and how the specification provides a common way of defining events along with handy tools to process them.

I was wondering if there is something similar for commands sent from one service to another.
With CloudEvents is very clear how to model a **UserCreated** event but, is there a common way to model a **CreateUser** command? Does it make sense to use CloudEvents spec to model commands?

Any opinion will be much appreciated.

Comment: I was just wondering what did you do here as I am in the same situation as you. Trying to see if I can use the same envelope structure from CloudEvents but for commands.